# How can I back up new folder to google drive?

Tags: google-drive

I bought a new laptop and there is some files I want to back up to my Google Drive. In my google drive, there is a folder which stored files from my old laptop and I want to keep storing files in it. How can I back up my new file to the old folder?

Comment: Have you tried to just install the Google Backup and Sync client?

Answer (score 0):

In *Google Backup & Sync*, select the three-dot Menu, *Preferences*, then on the *My Computer* tab click *Choose Folder* in the right section below the selected folders. This will allow you to choose individual folder structures to backup.